# Can't play sound in Flutter Android using just_audio

Tags: flutter, just-audio

So, I'm trying to have this sound from Flutter assets when I click the button. And I've tried many different packages by this moment and none of them seems to work for me.
I'm constantly getting this:

```
D/ViewRootImpl( 8796): enqueueInputEventMotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=582.0, y[0]=1570.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=48512196, downTime=48512196, deviceId=-1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]( 8796): processMotionEvent MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=582.0, y[0]=1570.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=48512196, downTime=48512196, deviceId=-1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]( 8796): dispatchPointerEvent handled=true, event=MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=582.0, y[0]=1570.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=48512196, downTime=48512196, deviceId=-1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
W/Choreographer( 8796): Frame time is 0.144734 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]( 8796): processMotionEvent MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=582.0, y[0]=1570.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=48512312, downTime=48512196, deviceId=-1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]( 8796): dispatchPointerEvent handled=true, event=MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=582.0, y[0]=1570.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=48512312, downTime=48512196, deviceId=-1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 8796): Init e31da6b [ExoPlayerLib/2.13.1] [RMX2025CN, RMX2025, realme, 30]
D/AudioManager( 8796): getStreamVolume packageName=com.example.dicee_v2_red, index=14, streamType=3
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:579)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:260)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (Mp3Extractor, FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:92)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1026)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8796):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AudioPlayer( 8796): TYPE_SOURCE: None of the available extractors (Mp3Extractor, FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
E/flutter ( 8796): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: (0) Source error
E/flutter ( 8796): #0      AudioPlayer._load (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:716:9)
E/flutter ( 8796): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8796): #1      AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.setPlatform (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1096:28)
E/flutter ( 8796): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8796): 
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 8796): Release e31da6b [ExoPlayerLib/2.13.1] [RMX2025CN, RMX2025, realme, 30] [goog.exo.core]
```

But when I load my app in Web, it works perfectly fine. Why?

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) {
    runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Dicee'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade300,
          ),
          body: NewDice(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  });
}

class NewDice extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewDiceState createState() => _NewDiceState();
}

class _NewDiceState extends State<NewDice> {
  late AudioPlayer player;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    player = AudioPlayer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  int leftDiceNumber = 1;
  int rightDiceNumber = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Image.asset('assets/dice$leftDiceNumber.png'),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Image.asset('assets/dice$rightDiceNumber.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await player.setAsset('audio/roll.mp3');
            player.play();
            setState(() {
              rightDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
              leftDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
            });
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.blue.shade300,
          ),
          child: Text('Roll the dice!',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Please help :)
I have also tried flutter_audio_player 0.1.2 and many other packages... none seems to work...

tried audiofileplayer 2.0.1, another bug now...

```
I/AudiofileplayerPlugin(11305): onMethodCall: method = load
I/AudiofileplayerPlugin(11305): onMethodCall: method = play
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.flutter.plugins.audiofileplayer.ManagedMediaPlayer.play(boolean, int)' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305):     at com.google.flutter.plugins.audiofileplayer.AudiofileplayerPlugin.onMethodCall(AudiofileplayerPlugin.java:256)
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/MethodChannel#audiofileplayer(11305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/DartMessenger(11305): Uncaught exception in binary message listener
E/DartMessenger(11305): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/DartMessenger(11305):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:155)
E/DartMessenger(11305):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:253)
E/DartMessenger(11305):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/DartMessenger(11305):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/DartMessenger(11305):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/DartMessenger(11305):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/DartMessenger(11305):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/DartMessenger(11305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/DartMessenger(11305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/DartMessenger(11305):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/DartMessenger(11305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/flutter (11305): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(AudioPluginError, Could not create ManagedMediaPlayer:flutter_assets/assets/audio/roll2.wav, null, null)
E/flutter (11305): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7)
E/flutter (11305): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
E/flutter (11305): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11305): #2      Audio._sendMethodCall (package:audiofileplayer/audiofileplayer.dart:751:7)
E/flutter (11305): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11305): #3      Audio._load (package:audiofileplayer/audiofileplayer.dart:433:7)
E/flutter (11305): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11305): 
E/flutter (11305): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(AudioPluginError, Called play on an unloaded player: 8dbbdf54-e262-4c2a-af1c-e6cbff1ac399, null, null)
E/flutter (11305): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7)
E/flutter (11305): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
E/flutter (11305): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11305): #2      Audio._sendMethodCall (package:audiofileplayer/audiofileplayer.dart:751:7)
E/flutter (11305): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11305): #3      Audio._playNative (package:audiofileplayer/audiofileplayer.dart:661:7)
E/flutter (11305): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11305): #4      Audio._playHelper (package:audiofileplayer/audiofileplayer.dart:556:5)
E/flutter (11305): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11305): #5      Audio.play (package:audiofileplayer/audiofileplayer.dart:517:5)
E/flutter (11305): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11305):
```

Comment: tried audiofileplayer 2.0.1, another bug now...

Comment: It could be the encoding of the audio file (which might not be supported). If it is within your power to reformat it to a different encoding, try that.

Comment: @RyanHeise I am getting the same error for local audio assets, but the same audio file working fine as the network assets

Comment: I had this issue and it was due to a bad MP3 file (that apparently Chrome knows how to play but ExoPlayer does not).  I verified this by swapping in a known good MP3: `flutter.github.io/samples/game_template/assets/sfx/dsht1.mp3` .

Answer (score 1):

just_audio package has some issues with some emulators. You can create another emulator and probably it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was due to a bad MP3 file (that apparently Chrome knows how to play but ExoPlayer does not). I verified this by swapping in a known good MP3: `flutter.github.io/samples/game_template/assets/sfx/dsht1.mp3` .

Try replacing your file with that and see if it works.